# how to "get" an exception context for error handling?

Tags: powershell, exception

I have a script that runs great but i am considering enhancing it by adding more exception handling that i received in the past in case future users struggle and need a clear hint at the possible solution to fix the problem if it were to occur sometime later.

What i essentially want to do is lets say as soon as i tried running the script, i got an execution policy exception of unauthorized access to run the script.

i dont want to spit the exception to a log file which then i can get-content of some string in there to print a possible solution.

instead, i want to grab a portion of the exception's string right away, from the console, then hint at what a solution could be.

is there such option?

Comment: In a `catch` block of a `try/catch`, there is a pipeline object (`$_` or `$PSItem`) of type `ErrorRecord` where you can access the different members of the thrown exception (including its type: `$_.Exception.GetType().FullName`).  Using this information, you can filter which catch blocks handle which exception.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 yes i think thats what I am aiming for! how would i be able to filter btw? right now i have this for output log file selecting string: Get-Content $output | Select-String "cannot be found" -quiet. is select-string what i use to filter?

Comment: If you only want one catch statement, you can use a switch: `switch -Regex ($_.Exception.Message)`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Sorry i didn't see you were already commenting on this. Looks like we had same ideas. I am impressed with myself.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 yes but where/how would I select a certain string like ”cannot be fiund”?

Comment: That would be in the `$_.Exception.Message`: `if ($_.Exception.Message -match 'cannot be found') {`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 whoops, just saw your post below. Looks like that's what I'm looking for ^_^

Comment: If my answer resolved your question, please mark it as the answer.  I'm glad to have helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to use the [`File.WriteAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.7.2) method for my example here.  If your goal is to have a single catch statement, you can use a switch on the exception message:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
try
{
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines('C:\Temp\test.txt', 'Test message')
}
catch
{
    switch -Regex ($PSItem.Exception.Message)
    {
        'null'
        {
            'null path passed!'
        }

        'invalid'
        {
            'bad path passed!'
        }

        default
        {
            'didn''t catch this case!'
        }
    }
}
```

This way isn't very maintainable, though.  A better way would be to catch the different exceptions:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
try
{
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines('C:\Temp\test.txt', 'Test message')
}
catch [System.ArgumentNullException]
{
    'null path passed!'
}
catch [System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException]
{
    'bad path passed!'
}
catch
{
    'didn''t handle this case!'
}
```

---

For your exception case running a script:

```
try
{
    & 'C:\myscript.ps1'
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.PSSecurityException]
{
     "Execution policy bad! $PSItem"
}
catch
{
    "This exception was thrown by something in the script and not caught: $PSItem"
}
```

Comment: What's $ErrorActionPreference for/do?

Comment: @Cataster that forces powershell to treat all exceptions as *terminating errors* which in turn makes sure the catch block is actually entered when an exception is thrown.  It's like adding `-ErrorAction Stop` to all statements.

Comment: Wait doesn't the file write mean there is an out file created to get the string from as opposed to my request of no file involvement? Or is the file written nothing to do with the exception message?

Comment: @Cataster file write was just to illustrate different exceptions that could be thrown linked to documentation as an example.

Comment: oh i see. i think i was looking for a more general exception handling, so not specifically a certain exception (like file IO). I think your comment nailed it though! $_.Exception.Message: if ($_.Exception.Message -match 'cannot be found') {

Comment: i guess what im trying to say is does the try block have to have anything in there? i want to get all possible exception messages (like the execution policy exception) and run the filter string on that to see if a certain string match exists to print some resolution steps.

Comment: Whatever you're expecting to throw an exception needs to be in the try block @Cataster

Comment: ok, one more thing. is there an option for try to say something like: try running the script, so something like "start script", and if it cant run it then it executes the catch block of exception

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Try Catch** method in Powershell. Combine with a switch you can sort out what messages you want to display.

```
try{
    sdasdasdad
}catch [System.Exception]{
    switch ($_.Exception.GetType().FullName){
        "System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException"{
            "No Command Found. Please try a diffrent command."
        }
        default { 
            $_.Exception.message
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like that's another good method of what I'm looking for :)

Comment: does try have to have something in there? can't it be empty?

Comment: sure but why would you want it empty?

Comment: because in my case, as soon as i load the powershell script, it may throw an execution policy exception. so not even running any of the commands in the script yet, theerfore, i have nothing to try against. so the try statement will be at the very beginning of the script